# Amazon MWS PHP Client Library seems incomplete

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am trying to develop an application that uses the `ListMatchingProducts` method.

The end result will be an application that searches for a given product which is already in an internal stock database and present the results to the user so they can select which Amazon product is a correct match for the one in their database.

The PHP Client Library I found is linked [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html/141-5495340-4494304).

I have edited Samples/.config.inc.php correctly (I have removed the comments and redacted the sensitive information):

```
define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '/*REDACTED BUT SET CORRECTLY*/');
define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '/*REDACTED BUT SET CORRECTLY*/');
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'STES_MWS_STOCK_SYNC_APP');
define('APPLICATION_VERSION', '0.1');
define ('MERCHANT_ID', '/*REDACTED BUT SET CORRECTLY*/');
define ('MARKETPLACE_ID', 'A1F83G8C2ARO7P'); // Marketplace ID for the UK
```

I have also uncommented the appropriate line in Samples/ListMatchingProductsSample.php:

```
$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
```

Executing this script, however, yeilds the following message (I've redacted some of the XML response):

```
Caught Exception: Required parameter MarketplaceId not found
Response Status Code: 400
Error Code: MissingParameter
Error Type: Sender
Request ID: /*REDACTED UUID-LIKE STRING*/
XML: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>MissingParameter</Code><Message>Required parameter MarketplaceId not found</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestID>/*REDACTED UUID-LIKE STRING*/</RequestID></ErrorResponse>
ResponseHeaderMetadata: RequestId: /*REDACTED UUID-LIKE STRING*/, ResponseContext: /*REDACTED LONG STRING*/, Timestamp: 2017-04-24T13:25:33.533Z, Quota Max: 719.0, Quota Remaining: 719.0, Quota Resets At: 2017-04-24T14:03:00.000Z
```

As this client library has been around since 2011 I find it difficult to believe this is actually incorrect code in the sample, but I can't seem to find where I've gone wrong; scanning through the code I can't find a reference to the `MARKETPLACE_ID` constant defined in Samples/.config.inc.php

Before I write my own client library (which I had hoped to avoid for such a simple app) I wondered:

- Has anyone else had come across this problem and fixed it (and if so, how)?
- Is there a newer version of the library I'm not finding?
- Can anyone suggest an alternate library if this one really is broken?

-- EDIT --

For completeness, here is the code I am trying to run - the sample code - minus comments:

```
 require_once('.config.inc.php');
 $serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
 $config = array (
   'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
   'ProxyHost' => null,
   'ProxyPort' => -1,
   'ProxyUsername' => null,
   'ProxyPassword' => null,
   'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
 );
 $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client(
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        APPLICATION_VERSION,
        $config);
 $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ListMatchingProductsRequest();
 $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
 invokeListMatchingProducts($service, $request);
 function invokeListMatchingProducts(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
  {
      try {
        $response = $service->ListMatchingProducts($request);

        echo ("Service Response\n");
        echo ("=============================================================================\n");

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        echo $dom->saveXML();
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

     } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex) {
        echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
        echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
        echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
        echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should provide your code showing how you're using the SDK?

Comment: Thanks - I've added it, although I'm not sure it provides any helpful information

Comment: Frankly it seems like the "samples" are a bit naff. Looking at the code, it seems likely you need t o set the marketplaceId in the constructor in an associative array, or it looks like you can set it as though it was a property.

Comment: I agree, but looking through the actual class definitions I can't find anywhere in the actual library code to provide the marketplace ID. By the sounds of it I'm just going to have to code from scratch - It was just surprising to me that something that's been around for 6 years had never had this problem pointed out before, so I doubted my initial reaction of "this is a broken sample".

Comment: You could try adding `$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);`

Comment: Would you like to reword that as an answer so I can accept it? I did also have to add the query I was searching for - I think it's a case of poor documentation! I have to admit I was only looking for a method to provide it in to the constructor, not using a seperate method (embarassed face)

Comment: Done. Glad it worked. They really need to up their game... though I wouldn't hold my breath if they've not updated it in 6 years :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly it seems like the "samples" are a bit naff.

Looking at the code, it seems likely you need to set the marketplaceId manually, either in the constructor via an associative array or as a setter method call.

e.g.
`$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID)`

Comment: I added this under `$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);` and also added `$request->setQuery("query string");`